# Prevent scaling of printout of PDF without using hyperref

Tags: pdftex, primitives

pdftex produces PDF. We need a viewer to view the PDF and print it. Some of those viewers tend to scale the printout: the letters shrink. This is a bug especially of the Adobe Reader and explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204805/4736 .

A solution is describe here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165348/4736 :

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None}
```

I'd like to avoid `hyperref`, because it slows down compiling.

My question: Is there a command to do that without hyperref, maybe similar to `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`? (To avoid a misunderstanding: `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` does somethin completely different, I'm asking *if* there exists something like `\pdfprintscaling=0`.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### pdfTeX

The low level command for `\hypersetup{pdfprintscaling}` from the `hyperref` package with pdfTeX in PDF mode is:

```
\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
```

### LuaTeX

As child of pdfTeX it inherits some of the functionality of pdfTeX. `\pdfcatalog` is enabled by package `luatex85`:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
```

Without LaTeX/package `luatex85`:

```
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('', {'protected', 'pdfextension'})}
\protected\def\pdfcatalog{\pdfextension catalog }
\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
```

### dvips/ps2pdf

The special is:

```
\special{ps:[{Catalog}<</ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>>>/PUT pdfmark}
```

### XeTeX

```
\special{pdf:docview<</ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>>>}
```

Comment: Heiko, I dropped a few lines about that here: http://www.komascript.de/node/1897 -- in German, of course.

Comment: @KeksDose In my document I use `\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}`. The printer option is set to `Page scaling: none`: however, the left margin measures 3.5cm. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Marco Ask a separate question here and provide a minimal working example. By the way, I put the command `\pdfcatalog...` always before the document class.

Comment: Any chance to achieve the same without pdftex? For example, with lualatex?

Comment: @Twonky See updated answer.