# Ideal margins vs. actual margins

Tags: margins

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
   \usepackage{blindtext}
   \usepackage[inner=1cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}

   \begin{document}
      \blinddocument
   \end{document}
```

The expectation/desire of course is that the distance from the sides of the paper to the text body is exactly 1 cm.  However, when I print out a copy of this document and measure the *actual* distance from the edge of the paper to the text, it appears that the size of the margin is much closer to 1.5 cm.

Why?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your print settings. Oftentimes the default settings will try to "scale to printable area" for a document with narrow margins like this.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232712/7883