# What is the LuaTex equivalent to `\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}`

Tags: luatex, viewers, printing

With pdfLaTeX I prevent downsizing of printouts with `\pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}`.

Now how to use this with LuaLaTeX? I tried:

`{\pdfextension catalog=/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}`

and get the error message

```
Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
=
l.2 {\pdfextension catalog=
                         /ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
```

Texlive 2019 on Linux.

MWE:

```
{\pdfextension catalog=/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

I've seen this question: [Prevent scaling of printout of PDF without using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232712/4736),
but loading luatex85 seems a bit outdated, or am I wrong?

Comment: Why the equal sign? Use braces like with \pdfcatalog. But with hyperref you can set the option too.

Comment: Still using a package, `\usepackage{pdfbase}`, but shouldn't slow down compilation and works across all engines/drivers: `\ExplSyntaxOn\pbs_pdfcatalog:n{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @AlexG I'm using LaTeX3 in my document anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use braces like with `\pdfcatalog`:

```
     \pdfextension catalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
```