# Page scaling at print

Tags: pdf, texstudio, scaling, printing, page

I am *writing my thesis* with the Latex template provided by the university, and they are complaining that the margins are not right.

The .cls file I am using is provided by them and has the correct margin values. So somewhere when creating the .pdf there is some page scaling and *I don't know where or how to turn it off*!

I am using TeXstudio as my offline Tex editor, which compiles using PdfLaTeX and opens it in Acrobat. Should I change the **page scaling** in **TeXstudio** or **PdfLaTex** or **Acrobat**??? **And HOW**?

I can't use the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79025/overriding-printer-scaling-defaults-from-within-latex/165348#165348), because `hyperref` clashes with the thesis template I am using (I know... dumb). The solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232712/prevent-scaling-of-printout-of-pdf-without-using-hyperref/232718#232718) also doesn't work for me. I don't know in which part of the process the scaling is done or how to disable it. Help??

Comment: Can you provide a small dest document that replicates the problem? Is the default paper size of your tex distribution the same as for your university?

Comment: Have you checked that there is a consistent setting? All process use DinA4 or Letter or whatever? This may be when some part in the chain is using something else.

Comment: How do I check these things? Sorry, newbie here