# How can I set the PDF TrimBox dynamically (with a macro) and compiler independent?

Tags: pdf, expansion, expl3

## Introduction

At the moment I’m preparing a custom class which is likely to be compiled with XeTeX or LuaTeX. It is for a book layout that should be professionally printed and therefor I want to set the `TrimBox` of the output PDF. The problem is the size of the bleed is user defined by a key-val class option. Therefore I need to be able to use macros as part of the `\special`/`\pdfpageattr` commands.

## General Idea

The general Idea is to use either `\special`s (XeTeX) or `\pdfpageattr` (LuaTeX, PDFTeX) to set the TrimBox. The distinction of the compiler can be done with LaTeX3 `\sys_if_engine_` and also the TrimBox strings can be defined as token lists. Then I define a macro using the variable content (`:V`) of these token lists to write the correct values to the PDF.

## Code

This is the minimal example code I came up with.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% bleed value (keyval class option in real document)
\dim_new:N \g_@@_bleed_dim 
\dim_set:Nn \g_@@_bleed_dim { 3mm }

%% set page size (and other stuff in the real document)
\usepackage { geometry }
   \geometry { papersize = { 185mm , 245mm } }

%% set crop size
\usepackage [ center ] { crop }
   \CROP@size {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperwidth + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   } {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperheight + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   }

%% new variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { N }

% values for the rim box
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl {
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:N \g_@@_bleed_dim \c_space_token
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:N \g_@@_bleed_dim \c_space_token
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \g_@@_bleed_dim } \c_space_token
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperheight + \g_@@_bleed_dim }
}

%% special for use with XeTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_special_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_special_tl {
   pdf: \c_space_token put \c_space_token @thispage \c_space_token
   << \c_space_token /TrimBox \c_space_token [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ] \c_space_token >>
}

%% page attribute for use with LuaTeX and PDFTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl {
   /TrimBox \c_space_token [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ]
}

%% command to set the specials for xetex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_special:n #1 {
   \AtBeginShipout { \immediate \special { #1 } }
   \immediate \special { #1 }
}

%% command to set the page attributes for pdftex/luatex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_pdfpageattr:n #1 {
   \pdfpageattr { #1 }
}

%% make a variants to make sure we get the expaned content
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_special:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_pdfpageattr:n { V }

%% [A] THIS DOES NOT WORK!
%% set the trim box according to engine
%\bool_if:nTF { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: || \sys_if_engine_pdftex_p: } {
%   \@@_pdfpageattr:V \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
%} {
%   \sys_if_engine_xetex:TF {
%      \usepackage{atbegshi}
%      \@@_special:V \g_@@_trim_special_tl
%   } { ERROR: UNKOWN MACHINE! }
%}

%% just a macro to show some debug info
\NewDocumentCommand { \debuginfo } { } {
   \par\noindent
   Machine: ~ \texttt{ \c_sys_engine_str }

   \par\bigskip\noindent
   special: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_special_tl } }

   \par\medskip\noindent
   pageattribute: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% [B] THIS WORKS!
%% for pdftex and luatex
%\pdfpageattr { /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] }
%% for xetex
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
%\AtBeginShipout { \special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> } }
%\special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> }

\begin{document}
\section*{Test Document}
\debuginfo \clearpage Just another page \ldots
\end{document}
```

## Result

Unfortunately my idea doesn’t work as expected.

When using the manual setup (`[B]` in the code) everything is fine and the TrimBox is set up properly for PDFTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX. But when using the auto generated token lists instead (`[A]` in the code), it does not work: With XeTeX I get a PDF but without any TrimBox settings and with PDFTeX or LuaTeX the PDF file is corrupted and can’t be opened with a viewer even uncompressing it with `cpdf` fails.

## Question

Simple: What’s my mistake?

## Notes

If this question leads to a robust code I would make a package out of it an publish it on CTAN.

While researching I found the following questions and want to make clear that this is not a duplicate question ;-)

- [Embedding printer settings in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34540/4918) – as far as I understand `pdfprintclip` is only a vier setting but to be honest I did’t test it because I couldn’t figure out how to use it.
- [Problem with setting correct custom page size with 'geometry' in xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55707/4918) – is only about the visual page layout and not the PDF-TrimBox
- [How to use macro inside \pdfpageattr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248902/4918) – actually shows how to use a macro (aka dynamic values) for the TrimBox but I couldn’t transfer the answer to my LaTeX3 approach
- [Producing PDF/X compliant document with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255480/4918) – contains only information about setting the box manually with XeTeX.

Furthermore the `pdf` packages seems to be no help in this case. At least I can’t find anything about trimming in the manual …

Comment: So where is the package? :P

Comment: Somewhere at the very bottom of my loooong to do list … sorry ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `\c_space_token` does not expand to a space, I used `\space` here.  It is `\let` to a space so it is an unexpandable implicit character, if you uncomment the first line with `\pdfcompresslevel` so the pdf stream is readable you will see that `\c_space_token` is written literally into the pdf stream between the trim box coordinates. Conversely `\space` is a macro that expands to a space character.

```
%\pdfcompresslevel0
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% bleed value (keyval class option in real document)
\dim_new:N \g_@@_bleed_dim 
\dim_set:Nn \g_@@_bleed_dim { 3mm }

%% set page size (and other stuff in the real document)
\usepackage { geometry }
   \geometry { papersize = { 185mm , 245mm } }

%% set crop size
\usepackage [ center ] { crop }
   \CROP@size {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperwidth + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   } {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperheight + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   }

%% new variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { N }

% values for the rim box
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl {
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:N \g_@@_bleed_dim \space 
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:N \g_@@_bleed_dim \space
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \g_@@_bleed_dim } \space
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperheight + \g_@@_bleed_dim }
}

%% special for use with XeTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_special_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_special_tl {
   pdf: ~ put ~ @thispage ~
   << ~ /TrimBox \space [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ] ~ >>
}

%% page attribute for use with LuaTeX and PDFTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl {
   /TrimBox \space [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ]
}




%% command to set the specials for xetex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_special:n #1 {
   \AtBeginShipout { \immediate \special { #1 } }
   \immediate \special { #1 }
}

%% command to set the page attributes for pdftex/luatex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_pdfpageattr:n #1 {
   \pdfpageattr { #1 }
}

%% make a variants to make sure we get the expaned content
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_special:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_pdfpageattr:n { V }

%% [A] THIS DOES NOT WORK!
%% set the trim box according to engine
\bool_if:nTF { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: || \sys_if_engine_pdftex_p: } {
   \@@_pdfpageattr:V \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
} {
   \sys_if_engine_xetex:TF {
      \usepackage{atbegshi}
      \@@_special:V \g_@@_trim_special_tl
   } { ERROR: UNKOWN MACHINE! }
}

%% just a macro to show some debug info
\NewDocumentCommand { \debuginfo } { } {
   \par\noindent
   Machine: ~ \texttt{ \c_sys_engine_str }

   \par\bigskip\noindent
   special: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_special_tl } }

   \par\medskip\noindent
   pageattribute: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% [B] THIS WORKS!
%% for pdftex and luatex
%\pdfpageattr { /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] }
%% for xetex
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
%\AtBeginShipout { \special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> } }
%\special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> }

\begin{document}
\section*{Test Document}
\debuginfo \clearpage Just another page \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thanks! Just find out that `\c_space_tl` works too so I’m using this because it feels more constituent in the context of LaTeX3 …

Comment: Tobi and David; it was an excellent effort, thanks for this, just a small clarification, is it possible to fix this in LaTeX + dvips + Ps2PDF? Please suggest...

Comment: David, Is it possible to fix the BleedBox by using your suggestion? Please ...