# How to set TrimBox in PDF by using PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, trimbox

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[cam,a4,info,center]{crop}

\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{6truein}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-3pc}%
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{3pc}%

%\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength\topmargin{-34pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test Document}

Just another page \ldots

\end{document}
```

And the output produced as follows:

[image]

I am using MikTeX 2.9 and PDFLaTeX to generate the output. How can I set the TrimBox in PDF by using this method? Please suggest...

I've tried further, fixed the TrimBox in PDF issue with the tag:

```
\pdfpageattr{/TrimBox [36 36 468 684]%
}%
```

And the output comes as:

[image]

But the `TrimBox` not exactly comes with the `Cropmarks`, see the screenshot below for your reference:

[image]

Please suggest...

Comment: Do you want the TrimBox to be different from the CropBox? It may be that the example in section 2.5 of the documentation for `crop` answers your question.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for your hints, but in that section it was suggested by using the package "geometry", is this possible without using "geometry" package? ....

Comment: you can look at the `geometry` source code for inspiration and implement your own page size macros. Or try to find a way to enable using the package of course.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297573/how-can-i-set-the-pdf-trimbox-dynamically-with-a-macro-and-compiler-independen solved my question...Thanks a lot `DavidCarlisle`...