# How to set trim box in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, trimbox

Please suggest me how to fix trim, bleed and art box in xelatex. Here I used the below code it supports only in pdflatex not for xelatex. It will be grateful someone can provide the better solution. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}   

\makeatletter    
\pdfpageattr{
/MediaBox [0 0 612.00000 792.00000]
/BleedBox [81.0 63.0 531.0 729.0]
/CropBox [0 0 612.00000 792.00000]
/TrimBox [90.0 72.0 522.0 720.0]
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Between 200BC and 100BC, during the Han Dynasty, the Chinese used matrix-type methods with the text \textit{Nine chapters on the mathematical art}. There was further development, but it was not until 1683 when the idea of a determinant appeared in Japan when Seki wrote \textit{Method of solving the dissimulated problems}. This used matrix methods in tables in the same way as the earlier work of the Chinese. Ten years later the determinant first appeared in Europe in the work of Leibniz. The word determinant was first introduced by Gauss in 1801 while discussing quadratic forms, but Cauchy in 1812 used determinant in the modern sense.

Between 200BC and 100BC, during the Han Dynasty, the Chinese used matrix-type methods with the text \textit{Nine chapters on the mathematical art}. There was further development, but it was not until 1683 when the idea of a determinant appeared in Japan when Seki wrote \textit{Method of solving the dissimulated problems}. This used matrix methods in tables in the same way as the earlier work of the Chinese. Ten years later the determinant first appeared in Europe in the work of Leibniz. The word determinant was first introduced by Gauss in 1801 while discussing quadratic forms, but Cauchy in 1812 used determinant in the modern sense.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297573/87678

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dvipdfmx`/ Xe(La)TeX equivalent of `\pdfpageattr` is `@thispage`, which allows adding PDF code to the current page object using the `pdf:put` special:

```
\special{pdf:put @thispage << ... >>}
```

Settings made with `\pdfpageattr` are applied to all pages that follow its call. With XeTeX/dvipdfmx however, the effect of `@thispage` is limited to the current page. To extend it to multiple or all document pages the above-mentioned special must be repeatedly inserted.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{
  \special{pdf:put @thispage <<
    /MediaBox [0 0 612.00000 792.00000]
    /BleedBox [81.0 63.0 531.0 729.0]
    /CropBox [0 0 612.00000 792.00000]
    /TrimBox [90.0 72.0 522.0 720.0]
  >>}
}}

\begin{document}
Between 200BC and 100BC, during the Han Dynasty, the Chinese used matrix-type methods with the text \textit{Nine chapters on the mathematical art}. There was further development, but it was not until 1683 when the idea of a determinant appeared in Japan when Seki wrote \textit{Method of solving the dissimulated problems}. This used matrix methods in tables in the same way as the earlier work of the Chinese. Ten years later the determinant first appeared in Europe in the work of Leibniz. The word determinant was first introduced by Gauss in 1801 while discussing quadratic forms, but Cauchy in 1812 used determinant in the modern sense.

Between 200BC and 100BC, during the Han Dynasty, the Chinese used matrix-type methods with the text \textit{Nine chapters on the mathematical art}. There was further development, but it was not until 1683 when the idea of a determinant appeared in Japan when Seki wrote \textit{Method of solving the dissimulated problems}. This used matrix methods in tables in the same way as the earlier work of the Chinese. Ten years later the determinant first appeared in Europe in the work of Leibniz. The word determinant was first introduced by Gauss in 1801 while discussing quadratic forms, but Cauchy in 1812 used determinant in the modern sense.
\end{document}
```

Comment: After compiling your example with xelatex I get the following result from pdfinfo: 
Creator:         XeTeX output 2019.10.09:0943
Producer:       xdvipdfmx (20190503)
[...]
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
CropBox:            0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
File size:      11491 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5

Comment: BleedBox, CropBox and TrimBox all are equal to MediaBox.

Comment: @andc You are right, only the `CropBox` is inheritable acc. to the PDF specification and can be set in the root node of the page tree. The other boxes must be set for every page individually. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!